# a field name "ClassName" is being inserted into mongodb by morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm pretty new to mongodb and morphia, after starting using it, I realize that there is a extra part in mongodb document, the record contains a filed name "ClassName" with value of the class that morphia mapped.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51e7a85e300441e5885316c0"), "className" : "models.User", "imgurl" : "", "uname" : "alex"}
```

is this normal? i feel it is violating the integrity of the data in the db, is there anyway to get around it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can explicitly disable the `className` attribute: `@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)`

I'm generally suppressing the attribute, if there is a single entity class. If I'm subclassing my entity, I'm explicitly enabling it (which is the default, but just to be sure).

If I'm not mistaken, Morphia is clever enough to guess the correct subclass based on the properties even if there is no `className` (based on reflection). So if you have an attribute *mongoKnowledge* in your subclass *Developer* of *Person* and your subclass *Manager* doesn't have it, Morphia will know that documents with *mongoKnowledge* must be of the class *Developer*. So strictly speaking `className` is only required if your subclasses have the same attributes; however, I wouldn't rely on it too much.

I haven't tried to rename the entity classes, but it will probably cause issues. There's a long standing issue to provide a `@Polimorphic` annotation and to fix it together with that. See https://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?id=22

Comment: I ran a simple test to see if Morphia will discriminate based on data fields, and it does not appear to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Since Morphia supports Polymorphism, means subclasses shall be stored in the same collection where the super class is persisted. In order to differentiate/ filter while querying and storing, it uses this field. Hope you would use Morphia for querying also. How do you think, it affects the integrity of your data, as you could easily filter it out.

Hibernate too, has discriminator column for supporting polymorphism.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-discriminator

Comment: what happens if later I change the name of the class?? name refactoring happens pretty often, do I have to go through all the records and update them all?