# Field “ClassName” is inserted into mongodb by morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, classname

I want to save complex objects as a property of another object:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
public class User {
    ......
    @Embedded
    public Map<String, List<Order>> orders; 
    ......

}

@Embedded
public class Order {

   String productName;
   String description;
..........

}
```

Than map is set in code using setter:

```
Map<String, List<Order>> ordersMap = new HashMap<>();
ordersMap.put(...);
user.setOrders(ordersMap);
```

But in document 'User' every Order is saved with field 'className' in map 'orders' :

"1" :[ {"className": "com.domain.Order",
       "productName" : "Milk",
       "description": "Fresh"
       }
     ]

**What is needed to do to not save field 'className' for Order inside ordersMap?**

Comment: please refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719018/a-field-name-classname-is-being-inserted-into-mongodb-by-morphia

Comment: Thank you!
But Order is not an entity , it`s an embedded object. Nevertheless @Entity(noClassnameStored = true) will help?

Comment: Unfortunately, @Entity(noClassnameStored = true) didn't help:
`@Embedded
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true) 
public class Order{
....
}`